# How to set up a directory as a "module" for bulk JavaScript import?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just like we'd do
`import * as React from 'react';`
and then for example
`const [state, setState] = React.useState(false);`

I would like to import a bunch of my exported stuff from a folder to then access using dot-notation of the imported module.

For example, an "AppBar" component using "AppsButton", "HomeButton", "BugReportButton" and "HelpButton", which I put as jsx files in the same folder. These files each "export default" functions for their views. I would like to do:

```html
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import * as AppBarContent from ".//AppBar"; // hopefully the correct syntax for the folder named "AppBar", which this file sits in
```

and then use each component in the view like:

```html
<AppBar>
    <AppBarContent.AppsButton />
    <AppBarContent.HomeButton />
    <AppBarContent.BugReportButton />
    <AppBarContent.HelpButton />
</AppBar>
```

I looked about and found [this resource](https://riptutorial.com/node-js/example/21102/folder-as-a-module), but wasn't certain it's the same thing I'm after and when I made the suggested index.js with the following content it didn't change anything (I could've done it wrong).

*index.js:*

```html
exports.AppsButton = require("./AppsButton");
exports.HomeButton = require("./HomeButton");
exports.BugReportButton = require("./BugReportButton");
exports.HelpButton = require("./HelpButton");
exports.HelpDrawer = require("./HelpDrawer");
```

Any single resource or some steps how to achieve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the solution to this when checking out some coding standards for React:
[image]

One point says "Create a index.js within each folder for exporting".
Source: https://www.jondjones.com/frontend/react/react-tutorials/react-coding-standards-and-practices-to-level-up-your-code/

After I've added an `index.js` to each folder that imports all components in that folder and then exports them all, I can **import individual components** from that folder level as a "module" (apologies if terminology incorrect) and also **import all as a named source** that I can access using dot notation.
Note that for this to work the imports (of indexed exports) must now include curly braces.

For example all the buttons going into a new folder "buttons" and having an `index.js`:

```html
import AppsButton from "./AppsButton";
import HomeButton from "./HomeButton";
import AppHomeButton from "./AppHomeButton";
import HelpButton from "./HelpButton";

export {AppsButton, HomeButton, AppHomeButton, HelpButton}
```

Then the `AppBar.js` a folder up can do either:

```html
import {AppsButton, HomeButton, AppHomeButton, HelpButton} from "./buttons"
```

with

```html
<AppBar>
    <AppsButton />
    <HomeButton />
    <BugReportButton />
    <HelpButton />
</AppBar>
```

or:

```html
import * as buttons from "./buttons"
```

with:

```html
<AppBar>
    <buttons.AppsButton />
    <buttons.HomeButton />
    <buttons.BugReportButton />
    <buttons.HelpButton />
</AppBar>
```

(I went for the former in this case, but I can see now how in other areas of my code-base I could have things like appBarContent.buttons.AppsButton reused elsewhere using this approach...)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have more than one default export in one file. Use named exports as follows:

appbar.js:

```
export const BugReport = () => <div> bug </div>
export const Header = () => <div> header </div>
export const Footer = () => <div> Footer </div>
```

Then you can import and use them as follows:

header.js

```
import React from "react";
import * as Appbar from "./appbar";

function Header(props) {
  return (
      <div>
        <Appbar.BugReport/>
        <Appbar.Footer/>
        <Appbar.Header/>
      </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Also, in the `appbar.js` file, you can import the components (BugReport, Footer etc.) and then export each one with `export const`.

Comment: Thank you for the response Hasan, based on that I thought I needed the following in an AppBarComponents.js:
import AppsButtonComponent from "./AppsButton";
...
export const AppsButton = () => <AppsButtonComponent />
...
then in AppBar.js:
import * as AppBarContent from './AppBarComponents';
...
<AppBarContent.AppsButton />

This didn't actually work so I clearly haven't understood what you've suggested.

This approach seems like I'll need the individual imports anyway, which points to not bothering and just importing each.

But it would be good to use it as a module like React.